# Deleted index appearing in Elasticsearch /_status

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an index appearing in my ES cluster's `/_status` listing, called `users_54ac2d97de674204ddd61096`.  However, if I try to GET (or DELETE) `/users_54ac2d97de674204ddd61096`, I get the folowing 404 response:

```
{
  "error": "RemoteTransportException[[Photon][inet[/10.10.2.72:9300]][indices:admin/get]]; nested: IndexMissingException[[users_54ac2d97de674204ddd61096] missing]; ",
  "status":404
}
```

If I try to recreate this index, I end up with a second index with that name in the listing.

How did I get into this state, and how can I get out of it?

Comment: Can you update your question with what you get when running this `curl 'localhost:9200/_cat/indices?v'`

Comment: I will do that if I ever find myself in this state again. It was a while ago, and I believe I worked around this issue by just blowing everything away and rebuilding my indices :/

Comment: Sometimes, that's the way to do it, indeed ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try using the head plugin. It usually works for me if the usual delete operation fails.
https://github.com/mobz/elasticsearch-head